# Powershell script to export windows version and SamAccountName on Windows 10 clients in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I hope someone here can help me designing a powershell script to do the following:

- Find all windows 10 clients in AD, and also get the either SamAccountName OR last SamAccountName logged, in on the windows 10 clients, when the script is executed.
- Export Last login, `SamAccountName`, `OperationSystem` and `OperationSystemVersion` to an Excel document.

I have the following code so far:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion | Export-CSV C:\AllWindows1.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

But I need this to fetch the logged in/last login of the `SamAccountName` also, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do something like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion,SamAccountName

Foreach ($computer in $computers) 
{
    if ($computer.OperatingSystemVersion -like '10.0*')
    {
        $obj = New-Object psobject
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Name $computer.Name
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Operating System' $computer.OperatingSystem
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'Operating System Version' $computer.OperatingSystemVersion
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty 'SAMAccountName' $computer.samaccountname

        $obj | Export-CSV C:\AllWindows1.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
    }
}
```

But this is not finding what was the last account login to the Win10 computer.
I was checking the properties for the computer object in AD, and there is no such thing. I believe that you would have to write a pretty complex script in order to determine who was the last person who logged in to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want as a computer object does not have an attribute that holds details of the last user that logged.

You would need to either, write a logon script that saves the login information to a database/log file however or [enable auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787176(WS.10).aspx) for account logon events.

Auditing [events](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787567(WS.10).aspx) will then be saved to the DC security log and can be read using `Get-EventLog`.